# Ubuntu 14.04 Calculator does not get focus when opened from keyboard shortcut

Tags: unity, keyboard, shortcut-keys, 14.04, focus

I am using a Microsoft Natural® Ergonomic Keyboard 4000 on my Ubuntu 14.04 x64 and since I upgraded from Ubuntu 13.10 I noticed that the Calculator application does not get focus when started from the keyboard shortcut. It gets started like the last (NOT previous) application in the stack.

It gets focus when opened from dash.

I don't know what configuration output to provide. Any suggestions?

Comment: I fixed this using key binding in compiz http://askubuntu.com/questions/321525/how-to-connect-a-calculator-button-on-a-keyboard-with-a-call-of-a-calculator

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**What you have discovered seems to be a bug related to some applications launched from (unity)*-settings-daemon.**  The bug is reported [here.](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-calculator/+bug/1304696)

However, it exist multiple easy workarounds to this annoying issue;

The one I will suggest, is to define your own keyboard shortcut, and reassign the calculator button.

[image: keyboard shortcut]

---

Another solution is to:

Use eg. `CompizConfig Setting Manager` and set the `Focus Prevention Level` option to off. The option is found under `General Options` on the tab named `Focus & Raise Behaviour`.

Comment: today's upgrade seems to have fixed it.

Comment: Hi, the proposed answer is not what I expected. I want to have focus prevention and have my calculator app to gain focus when launched from keyboard. Is that possible?

Comment: You can have focus prevention with suggestion one.

Comment: Well, I my particular case, If I create a custom shortcut using the calculator button on my keyboard, the calculator app doesn't show at all...

Comment: The alternative solution (using CompizConfig) resolved the problem for me, as by adding a custom shortcut, the application did open on top of other apps, but didn't receive focus and thus still didn't receive immediate input.

Comment: After creating your own keyboard shortcut make sure to logout. When you log back in the shortcut will start working.

Comment: I don't have a "calc" button on my keyboard, but I always map `Super-C` to the calculator (via `System-Settings->Keyboard->Shortcuts->Launchers`), and this problem has been driving me batty. I disabled the built-in shortcut, added a `Custom Shortcut`, and now it works great, thanks (no log-out required; hopefully it still works when I do log out!).